# Why does Honeywell POS4NET fire the same event for two different scanners?

Tags: c#, point-of-sale

I want to read input from two Honeywell scanners, namely *Voyager 1202g* and *Orbit 7190g*. For some business requirements, both devices need to be used from  the same machine. *Both* scanners use the Honeywell POS4NET driver.

I need to know, **which** scanner is delivering the data.

The `Scanner` objcts are created as follows

```
// This code is only for illustrating how my application works
// and may therefore be incomplete.

Microsoft.PointOfService.PosExplorer posExp = new PosExplorer(this);
DeviceCollection devices = posExp.GetDevices("Scanner", 
    DeviceCompatibilities.OposAndCompatibilityLevel1);
var listOfScanners =  { Voy1202g ,  Orbit7190g };     // symbolical code

foreach (string device in listOfScanners)
{
    var scanningDevice = posExp.CreateInstance(device) as Microsoft.PointOfService.Scanner;
    if (scanningDevice != null)
    {
        scanningDevice.Claim(1000);
        scanningDevice.DeviceEnabled = true;
        scanningDevice.DataEvent += ScanningDevice_DataEvent;
        scanningDevice.DecodeData = true;
        scanningDevice.DataEventEnabled = true;
        scanningDevice.ErrorEvent += ScanningDevice_ErrorEvent;
    }
}
```

**Problem:** When reading data inside the event handler `ScanningDevice_DataEvent`, I can no longer distinguish between them, because for both scanners, *the identical event is fired*, no matter which scanner is actually reading the barcode.

```
void ScanningDevice_DataEvent(object sender, DataEventArgs e)
{
    Scanner scanner = (Scanner)sender; // <--- sender is always the last one
                                       //       in listOfScanners, i.e. 
                                       //       Orbit7190g in this case. 
    // Additional code here ...

}
```

This issue only arises, when two scanners use the same driver. If I use two or more different scanners, that do not share the driver, it works as expected. It also does, if I start 2 different instances of my application, each one reading from one of the scanners.

**Question:** How can I make my application fire the correct event?

**Remark:** To me, it looks as if `Microsoft.PointOfService` holds a single instance of the handler *per ServiceObject type* , which, in this case, is always `HHP.PointOfService.ServiceObjects.Scanner.HandHeldScanner`. When changing the order in which the events are assigned,
the recognized scanner also changes.

Comment: I think you should be able to get IP.  See "Scoping the device selection" at : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/devices-sensors/pos-get-started

Comment: @mjwills Thanks for the hint; I added some explanatory code at the top of my listing

Comment: Oops, that's a typo. Fixed.

Comment: Maybe there is problem in driver, Honeywell do not provide usage of 2+ scanners with the same PC. Or they assume that scanned barcodes will be identified by type - i.e. the scanners are not differentiated. For example, if you have 2 USB keyboards, Windows will show entered characters from any keyboard. If you have 2 USB mouses, the mouse arrow will be moved equally by both mouses and you will not have 2 mouse arrows.