# Why isn't my scanner in the PosExplorer.GetDevices() list?

Tags: c#, barcode-scanner, pointofservice

The LS2208 scanner is plugged in, I tried the scanner modes listed below by reading barcodes I found in the manual. In "USB HID Keyboard" and "OPOS (IBM Hand-held with Full Disable)" modes I can read barcodes into a text document with the scanner.

USB HID Keyboard

IMB Table Top USB

IBM Hand-Held USB

OPOS (IBM Hand-held with Full Disable)

Simple COM Port Emulation

```
explorer = new PosExplorer();
scannerList = new ArrayList(explorer.GetDevices("Scanner"));
```

All I'm seeing in the list is two scanners, which are always visible even when nothing is plugged in the computer:

{
Service Object Name: Microsoft Scanner Simulator,
Description: Simulated service object for scanner,
Manufacturer: Microsoft Corporation,
Type: Scanner,
Service Object Version: 1.14.1.0,
UPOS Version: 1.14,
Compatibility: CompatibilityLevel1,
Hardware Description: ,
Hardware Id: ,
Hardware Path: ,
Default: False}

{Service Object Name: Example Scanner,
Logical Names: ,
Description: Service object for Example scanner,
Manufacturer: Microsoft Corporation,
Type: Scanner,
Service Object Version: 1.14.1.0,
UPOS Version: 1.14,
Compatibility: CompatibilityLevel1,
Hardware Description: ,
Hardware Id: ,
Hardware Path: ,
Default: False}

Trying to connect to either of them throws an exception: "The value of the 'DevicePath' property must be defined by the service object before Open() can be called."

I assumed the "Simple COM Port Emulation" mode would simulate serial port input, but the scanner did not appear in the serial port list either.

```
System.IO.Ports.SerialPort.GetPortNames();
```

Comment: Open device manager.  Check if the devices are colored yellow.  Also check the driver that is being used.  Often the default Microsoft Serial Driver is installed and you need the vendor driver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are confused about different kinds of usage.

- USB HID Keyboard
  It emulates keyboard input and requires no additional drivers or software.
  In other words, it cannot be controlled by software.
- `PointOfService` tag
  This mainly belongs to the API used in UWP, and it is necessary to set the hardware mode to use this method.
  The LS2208 may not support this mode.
  The DS2208 is supported.
  [Windows.Devices.PointOfService Namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.pointofservice)
  [Supported Point of Service Peripherals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/devices-sensors/pos-device-support)
- `scannerList = new ArrayList(explorer.GetDevices("Scanner"));`
  The software you are trying to use is POS for .NET.
  The LS2208 supports OPOS/JPOS, but does not directly support POS for.NET.
  [SYMBOL LS2208 GENERAL PURPOSE BARCODE SCANNER SUPPORT](https://www.zebra.com/us/en/support-downloads/scanners/general-purpose-scanners/ls2208.html)
  However, you can use OPOS from POS for .NET via Legacy Interop System.
  [POS for .NET Architecture (POS for .NET v1.12 SDK Documentation)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/embedded/bb429017(v=winembedded.11))

For that, the following steps are required.

- Install Zebra OPOS Driver (included in Scanner SDK for Windows).
  [Support and Downloads > OPOS Driver Downloads & Support](https://www.zebra.com/us/en/support-downloads/software/drivers/opos-driver.html) / [SCANNER SDK FOR WINDOWS](https://www.zebra.com/us/en/support-downloads/software/developer-tools/scanner-sdk-for-windows.html)
- Install CommonControlObjects.
  [MCS: OPOS Common Control Objects - Current Version](http://monroecs.com/oposccos_current.htm)
- Specify to search OPOS devices in the parameter of GetDevices().
  `DeviceCompatibilities.Opos` or `DeviceCompatibilities.OposAndCompatibilityLevel1`
  [PosExplorer.GetDevices Method (String, DeviceCompatibilities) (POS for .NET v1.12 SDK Documentation)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/embedded/ms843052(v=winembedded.11))
  [DeviceCompatibilities Enumeration (POS for .NET v1.12 SDK Documentation)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/embedded/ms884035(v=winembedded.11))

For example, please refer this article for how to use.
The question is not solved, but the usage of GetDevices() is okay.
[Why does Honeywell POS4NET fire the same event for two different scanners?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50351121/9014308)
[pos explorer is not finding any device connected to the system in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11411745/9014308)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I was not able to resolve the problem, but it might be just my incompetence. We will probably be using physical serial ports instead of multiple POS scanners.