# How to configure scanner to appear in PosExplorer.GetDevices() list?

Tags: c#, barcode-scanner

My scanner (CR5000) appears in Device Manager under the "POS Barcode Scanner" node as "POS HID Barcode scanner". Yet the scannerList does not contain a corresponding scanner.

```
explorer = new PosExplorer();
scannerList = new ArrayList(explorer.GetDevices("Scanner"));
```

All I'm seeing in the list is two other scanners, which are always visible even when nothing is plugged in the computer:

{ Service Object Name: Microsoft Scanner Simulator, Description: Simulated service object for scanner, Manufacturer: Microsoft Corporation, Type: Scanner, Service Object Version: 1.14.1.0, UPOS Version: 1.14, Compatibility: CompatibilityLevel1, Hardware Description: , Hardware Id: , Hardware Path: , Default: False}

{Service Object Name: Example Scanner, Logical Names: , Description: Service object for Example scanner, Manufacturer: Microsoft Corporation, Type: Scanner, Service Object Version: 1.14.1.0, UPOS Version: 1.14, Compatibility: CompatibilityLevel1, Hardware Description: , Hardware Id: , Hardware Path: , Default: False}

Trying to connect to either of them throws an exception: "The value of the 'DevicePath' property must be defined by the service object before Open() can be called."

Any suggestions on how to resolve this problem?

Comment: The situation is the same as in the previous article. [Why isn't my scanner in the PosExplorer.GetDevices() list?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62994014/9014308) Replace the OPOS driver part according to the vendor.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why isn't my scanner in the PosExplorer.GetDevices() list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62994014/why-isnt-my-scanner-in-the-posexplorer-getdevices-list)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I'm still trying to understand and follow the instructions.